# How to open asset studio in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

Asset studio is not showing in the `res` folder but showing in the search tab but when I try to open it from there nothing shows up.

The first time I open the android studio it had opened when I opened it from the search bar but not from the directory.

Answer (score -1):

**First**: Check if the folder really exists.

**Second**: Check the visibility of folders.

[image: Check if folder realy exists]

[image: Show visibility icons]